# Text input elements returning 'undefined' to .csv file

Tags: node.js, ejs

EDIT: I figured the problem out. It had turned out I was appending the items to themselves. The correct method I worked out would be to make a new variable as such:
`var form = document.getElementById("listItems");`

and then editing the `document.body.appendChild(itemName);` to
`form.appendChild(itemName)` and  `form.appendChild(itemQuantity)` respectively.

For context, the call to the backend looked as such:

```
   <form action="/buy" method=post id="listItems">
    <input type="submit" value="Send"> 
  </form>
```

---

When creating text boxes, I save the contents to a .csv file, however when I access these files I am returned a value of 'undefined'.

I looked into the code, and found that the input is saving itself as undefined no matter what was put in the text box.

Specifically these text boxes,

```
<script>
  function addItems(){
    var itemName = document.createElement("input");
    itemName.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    itemName.placeholder = "itemName";
    document.body.appendChild(itemName);


    var itemQuantity = document.createElement("input");
    itemQuantity.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    itemQuantity.placeholder = "itemQuantity";
    document.body.appendChild(itemQuantity);

  }
  </script>
```

`var itemName` and `itemQuantity` show up in console.log and in the file as undefined values.

What should've happened was that when I ran:

```
var itemN = req.body.itemName;
    var itemQ = req.body.itemQuantity;
    await fs.appendFile('receipt.csv', "\n" + itemN + " " + itemQ, err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
        console.log(itemN, itemQ);
        // done!
    })
```

It should have appended to the file 'receipt.csv' as `ItemN` + `ItemQ` as a string, however when accessed the file shows the submitted text as: Undefined Undefined.

Comment: are you calling addItems() that is defined in the script tags. Also put the ajax call to backend in the post.

Comment: Please provide code of the `form` or `ajax call` of your page